# How to grab the previous and next id from an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create next and previous buttons for my blog page. My blogs posts are stored within a table in my MySQL database. At the moment I'm getting the following result.

So I can get the **current id** and **current title**, but I'm not sure how to go about displaying the previous and next one on a page.

JavaScript code:

```
router.get('/posts/:permalinkSlug', async(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    var blogPostArray = []
    var results = await _db.rawSql('SELECT id, permalink_slug FROM blog_posts')
    blogPostArray.push(results)

    const permalinkSlug = req.params.permalinkSlug
    const post = await postTools.getPostByPermalinkSlug(permalinkSlug)
    res.locals.current_id = post.id
    console.log(res.locals.current_id)
    console.log(permalinkSlug)

    for (i = 0; i < blogPostArray.length; i++) {
      console.log(blogPostArray[i])
    }

    if (post) {
      res.render('post/post', {
        post: post,
        page: await _db.findOne('posts', {})
      })
    } else next()
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
})
```

New code:

```
var results = await _db.rawSql('SELECT id FROM blog_posts')
console.log(results)
```

Result:

```
[
  RowDataPacket { id: 12 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 13 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 14 },
  RowDataPacket { id: 15 } 
]
```

Comment: Question is not clear to me, try putting your code which you have tried!

Comment: Updated the question to hopefully make it slightly clearer. So the bottom part is the results of the code above it. I'm trying to work out the next and previous id and slug so i can use this on a blog post page to act as previous and next buttons

Comment: `blogPostArray[i-1]` and `blogPostArray[i+1]`?

Comment: Both return undefined unfortunately

Comment: only for the first and last iteration because the first one doesn't have a previous one and last one doesn't have a next one. You can check those with an if statement.

Comment: "res.locals.current_id" is this your current id

Comment: yes. That's what i want to pass to my handlebars file to show the prev/next dynamically

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mark, i see. I'll try and have a go at the if statement

Comment: permalinkSlug what does this do?

Comment: blogPostArray[res.locals.current_id-1],blogPostArray[res.locals.current_id+1], will do the trick, but check for -1 and length

Comment: that's the item which holds the path of the url, so each post has it's own permalinkSlug.

Comment: Okay thankyou Ullas, at the moment both are returning undefined.

Comment: In my mind because i'm on id 14, that has both a previous and next element so shouldn't be returning undefined

Answer (score 1):

If `res.locals.current_id` is giving a value then following will do the trick.

Replace this code like this:

```
blogPostArray.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)));
```

This is a bug as methioned [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1899).

```js
var blogPostArray = [{
    id: 12,
    permalink_slug: 'title1'
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    permalink_slug: 'title2'
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    permalink_slug: 'title3'
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    permalink_slug: 'title4'
  }
];
var res = {
  locals: {
    current_id: 14
  }
};
var index = blogPostArray.findIndex(x => Number(x.id) == Number(res.locals.current_id));
var next = getNext(index);
var prev = getPrev(index);
console.log(prev, next);

function getNext(sr) {
  sr = Number(sr);
  if (sr + 1 == blogPostArray.length) {
    return {}
  }
  return blogPostArray[sr + 1];//if not working try using blogPostArray[0][sr + 1] or blogPostArray[1][sr + 1]
}

function getPrev(sr) {
  sr = Number(sr);
  if (sr - 1 == -1) {
    return {}
  }
  return blogPostArray[sr - 1];//if not working try using blogPostArray[0][sr - 1] or blogPostArray[1][sr - 1]
}
```

inside the loop you can use the code as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < blogPostArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(getNext(i))
  console.log(getPrev(i))
}
```

Comment: thankyou for the detailed answer, i will give this a try

Comment: Sure, updated my answer with it. At the moment the code is returning empty objects regardless of what post it is on

Comment: Updated with working example, please upvote and accept if satisfies!

Comment: So console.log(nextItem) is returning all the ids, and console.log(prev) is returning undefined, regardless of what post it is on.

Comment: try updating var index = blogPostArray.findIndex(x => Number(x.id) == Number(res.locals.current_id));

Comment: Still returning undefined, could the problem be blogPostArray is returning rowpacketdata, since it's querying a mysql database

Comment: I've updated my OP with just conosle.log(results), so it's an object rather than an array

Comment: Yes, you have to format array before using it try using replace and format the array as I have done in the code.

Comment: To remove RowDataPacket  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)) use this

Comment: Updated the answer. Please do let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: I would love to say it's finished but unfortunately it's returning this, (i've removed the previous part for now). So the current id is 14, it's returning all the id's and the next function is returning an empty object
14
[ { id: 12 }, { id: 13 }, { id: 14 }, { id: 15 } ]
{}

Comment: what is the value of index is logging can you create  the fiddle for the this

Comment: index is returning -1.

Comment: index returns 0 to 3, using this;   var index = results.findIndex(x => x.id ===  res.locals.current_id);

Comment: @JohnDoi Create a code snippet that reproduces your problem so people can help easier.

Comment: Have updated the code with the comment try using that! please do let me know if still doesn't work and create filddle